# CoreData aggregates with subexpressions

Tags: ios, core-data

I've read everything I found on this topic here and everywhere, but still can't figure out how to do what I need.

I have a simple event object in core data db with properties like `title, status, startDate, endDate, dayDate`, where `status` is integer with 3 possible values and `dayDate` is date without time part (or midnight date).

I need to collect some statistics on events in the db, grouped by day and count of events with distinct status. In example I need results like following pseudo-dictionary:

`

```
[
@{
    @"dayDate" : ...someDate..
    @"eventsCountTotal" : 8,
    @"eventsWithStatus1" : 4,
    @"eventsWithStatus2" : 3,
    @"eventsWithStatus3" : 1
}
@{
    ...stats for another day
}
]
```

`

Is this possible using one query at all with CoreData? I'm currently doing this to get some stats, but it's not quite what I want:

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SWEvent"];
    request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dayDate < %@", [NSDate todayDate]];

    NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
    NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:@[keyPathExpression]];

    NSExpressionDescription * expressionDescription = [NSExpressionDescription new];
    expressionDescription.name = @"eventsCount";
    expressionDescription.expression = countExpression;
    expressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSInteger32AttributeType;

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SWEvent" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    NSDictionary *attributes = [entity attributesByName];
    NSAttributeDescription *statusDescription = attributes[@"status"];
    NSAttributeDescription *dayDateDescription = attributes[@"dayDate"];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dayDate" ascending:NO];

    request.predicate = predicate;
    request.propertiesToFetch = @[calledDescription, dayDateDescription, statusDescription];
    request.propertiesToGroupBy = @[dayDateDescription, statusDescription];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;

    @try {
        NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    }
    @catch(NSException *exception) {

        NSLog(@"Exception occurred: %@, %@", exception, [exception userInfo]);
    }
```

But this code gives me this, which is obviously what I don't want and would need to filter it further:
`

```
{
    status = 2;
    eventsCount = 1;
    dayDate = "2015-07-27 00:00:00 +0000";
},
{
    status = 1;
    eventsCount = 2;
    dayDate = "2015-07-26 00:00:00 +0000";
},
{
    status = 2;
    eventsCount = 3;
    dayDate = "2015-07-26 00:00:00 +0000";
}
```

`

Is there a way how to achieve what I need in one query or I really can't do any better than this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go for this case is to do it in memory, as recommended in the Core Data Programming Guide. I think it results in significantly less code. It would be interesting if you run into any performance or memory bottlenecks, but I would doubt it. (This should perform fine on old hardware with x0000 records.)

```
NSArray *allDates = [allEvents valueForKeypath:@"dayDate"];
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDate *date in allDates) {
   NSMutableDictionary *summary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
   NSArray *dayRecords = [allEvents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
       [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dayDate = %@", date]];
   [summary addObject:@{"dayDate" : date}];
   [summary addObject:@{"eventsCountTotal" : dayRecords.count}];
   for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
      NSArray *subgroup = [dayRecords filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
          [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status = %i", x]];
      [summary addObject:
          @{[NSString stringWithFormat:@"status%iCount", %@] : @(subgroup.count)}]
   }
   [result addObject:summary]
}
```

Comment: That's basically where I've ended up so far, but I was wondering if there's a way how to do it maybe more efficiently directly on CoreData layer. It seems there's no way indeed, so I accept your answer. Thank you.